# How to read csv file from s3 bucket in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-serverless

I am trying to read the content of a csv file which was uploaded on an s3 bucket. To do so, I get the bucket name and the file key from the event that triggered the lambda function and read it line by line. Here is my code:

```
import json
import os
import boto3
import csv

def lambda_handler(event,  context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        file_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        csvfile = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_key)
        csvcontent = csvfile['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
        data = []
        with open(csvfile['Body'], 'r') as csv_file:
          csv_file = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
          data = list(csv_file)
```

The exact error I’m getting on the CloudWatch is:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    with open(csvcontent, 'r') as csv_file:
```

Could someone help me fix this? I appreciate any help you can provide as I am new to lambda

Comment: `csvcontent` already contains your data. No need to open a file. `csvcontent` is actually a list of strings (lines) that you can parse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
csvfile = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_key)
csvcontent = csvfile['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
```

Here you have already retrieved the file contents and split it into lines. I'm not sure why you're trying to `open` something again, you can just pass `csvcontent` into your reader:

```
csv_data = csv.DictReader(csvcontent)
```

Comment: For small csvs yes. For large files this code will eat up all memory and get stuck

Comment: is s3 in your case boto3.client("s3") or boto3.resource("s3")     ?

Answer (score 24):

To get the CSV file data from s3 bucket in the proper and with easy to retrieve index format below code helped me a lot:

```
key = 'key-name'
bucket = 'bucket-name'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3_resource.Object(bucket, key)

data = s3_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()

lines = csv.reader(data)
headers = next(lines)
print('headers: %s' %(headers))
for line in lines:
    #print complete line
    print(line)
    #print index wise
    print(line[0], line[1])
```

Comment: do you know how to then get that csv file in lambda as the data frame?

Comment: Note if you are still getting weird characters using utf-8, try utf-8-sig as it reads the byte order mark as info instead of a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152985/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-sig

Answer (score 1):

`csvfile['Body']` type is `StreamingBody`, so you can't uses the `open xx with`.

this code had read all data from the stream.

```
csvcontent = csvfile['Body'].read().split(b'\n')
```

so jsut parse the line to get more usefully content.