# What is the difference between utf-8 and utf-8-sig?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I am trying to encode Bangla words in python using pandas dataframe. But as encoding type, utf-8 is not working but utf-8-sig is. I know utf-8-sig is with BOM(Byte order mark). But why is this called utf-8-sig and how it works?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python utf-8-sig BOM in the middle of the file when appending to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154355/python-utf-8-sig-bom-in-the-middle-of-the-file-when-appending-to-the-end)

Comment: I don't find anything related to the 'sig' part. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 80):

"sig" in "utf-8-sig" is the abbreviation of "signature" (i.e. signature utf-8 file).
Using utf-8-sig to read a file will treat the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) as metadata that explains how to interpret the file, instead of as part of the file contents. Read more [on Python's `codecs` documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html)"

> To increase the reliability with which a UTF-8 encoding can be
> detected, **Microsoft invented a variant** of UTF-8 (that **Python
> calls `"utf-8-sig"`**) for its Notepad program: Before any of the
> Unicode characters is written to the file, a UTF-8 encoded BOM (which
> looks like this as a byte sequence: 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf) is written.