# Cleaning/decoding scraped text in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, screen-scraping, decoding

I have a problem with converting text to csv after scraping. The point is, there are french letters which in .csv file ends up as "Ă©" "Ă‰" and so on. How can I decode it so they appear for example as english letters? or are properly scraped to file?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from urllib import request
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
html = request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Dieudonn%C3%A9")
bs = BS(html.read(), 'html.parser')
    
data = pd.DataFrame({'name':[],'known for':[],)}
    try:
        name = bs.find('h1').text
    except:
        name = ''
    try:
        known= bs.select_one('th:contains("Known")').next_sibling.get_text('\n').split('\n') #ends up with even more weird signs
    except:
        known = ''
x = {'name': name, 'known for': known}
data = data.append(x, ignore_index = True)
data.to_csv('files.csv', sep=",", index=True)
```

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply encode your data with `utf-8-sig`:

```
data.to_csv('files.csv', sep=",", index=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

---

From [What is the difference between utf-8 and utf-8-sig?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614459/13552470):

> `"sig"` in `"utf-8-sig"` is the abbreviation of "signature" (i.e. signature `utf-8` file). Using `utf-8-sig` to read a file will treat [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) *(Byte order mark)* as file info. instead of a string.