# Remove Special Character from tuple of list

Tags: python, tuples

I want to remove special characters from tuple. Consider an example

```py
(['\x0cSome Namel\n'],['\x0c4739 2332 3450 1111\n'])
```

I want to get output to be

```py
([Some Name ],[4739 2332 2450 1111])
```

I tried using `split` and `replace` even after using that it is returning same output

Comment: How do they get there in the first place? They are utf-8-sig. So there is a chance you can make the import and remove them on the import. Here is some info about utf-8-sig: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152985/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-sig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you have following string on input:

```
string = r"""['\x0cSome Namel\n'] ['\x0c4739 2332 3450 1111\n']"""
```

In this case you can use `replace` function:

```
string = string.replace(r"'\x0c", "").replace(r"\n'", "")
```

Output:

```
[Some Namel] [4739 2332 3450 1111]
```

Comment: This will remove it, but is a screw without end if you get new data that haven't been utf-8-sig encoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to remove the two characters shown in the question **and** if their position in each string is irrelevant then:

```
mytuple = ['\x0cSome Namel\n'], ['\x0c4739 2332 3450 1111\n']

for te in mytuple:
    for i, s in enumerate(te):
        te[i] = s.replace('\n', '').replace('\f', '')

print(mytuple)
```

**Output:**

```
(['Some Namel'], ['4739 2332 3450 1111'])
```